# Magento 2.4.3 change default product listing

Tags: magento2.4.3

I recently updated my testing environment to the new 2.4.2 version. But i have found something that does not seem right.

All the products used to load in from the newest ID to the oldest.
But since this new version it does the exact opposite.

i tried disabling all my templates and code and run on the default luma theme. But no luck there.

Does anybody know how i can get the default category page load to load in the products from the newest id to the oldest id? Without giving every product a new from date or anything to filter with?

Comment: It's a bug in Magento - It's currently being resolved in the priority queue. You'll need to use an extension to override it.

Comment: You need to do the customization code here according to your requirement.